# link to line instead of page

Tags: hyperref, indexing

I have got article where I try to build a working index with hyperlinks using `hyperref`. I made an example to reproduce:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xargs} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref} 


\pagestyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\makeindex
\begin{document} 
\section{Aufbau}
\cite{itu}
\subsection{Hardware}
\subsubsection{CPU Module}
\index{BeagleCore}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index}
\printindex 
\section{Literatur}
\bibliography{Literatur}
\end{document}
```

If I do now hit the index entry `BeagleCore` it jumps to the page. Is it possible to change the `hyperref` to point to the specific section / subsection instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no direct way to achieve this, since `hyperref` links the page for index entries, although there is something like `\hyperindexformat` in `hyperref`.

The linking format is written here by a redefinition of `\index` (adapted to `imakeidx` usage of multiple indexes:

`\imki@wrindexentry{\jobname}{#2|hyperlink{\@currentHref}}{\thepage}`

will write the index entry (#2) to the default file and install a hyperlink to the currently set anchor, which is stored in `\currentHref`. The anchor is achieved by placing a `\phantomsection` right at the position where the `\index` macro is applied.

The linking text is still using the page number, but the link leads to the line of the `\index` usage and not the top page anchor.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xargs} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{blindtext}


\pagestyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\makeindex[intoc]
\makeindex[name=foo, title=Foo index]

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \LetLtxMacro\egregs@index\index
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\index}{o+m}{%
    \begingroup
    \phantomsection%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
      \imki@wrindexentry{#1}{#2|hyperlink{\@currentHref}}{\thepage}%
    }{%
      \imki@wrindexentry{\jobname}{#2|hyperlink{\@currentHref}}{\thepage}%
    }%
    \endgroup
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\section{Aufbau}
%\cite{itu}
\subsection{Hardware}
\subsubsection{CPU Module}
\blindtext
Foo\index[foo]{BeagleCore}

Foo other\index{BeagleCore}
\clearpage
\printindex 

\clearpage
\printindex[foo]

\section{Literatur}
%\bibliography{Literatur}
\end{document}
```